# Ruby on rails pathname considered uninitialized constant in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes

In my Ruby on Rails app, when a user's authentication succeeds, I want to send him/her to a specific home page based on the account they belong to.

I tried adding an 'if' clause in my Sessions controller as follows :

```
def create
  if user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    if user.account.name == "X"
      redirect_to Xhome_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
    else
      redirect_to home_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
    end
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password combination"
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Copying the already existing following line in routes.rb :

```
match '/home' => "users#home", :as => "home"
```

I added this one :

```
match '/Xhome' => "users#Xhome", :as => "Xhome"
```

This does not work and gives the following results :

- if a user with user.account.name 'X' logs in, the browser displays the following error message :

  NameError in SessionsController#create

  uninitialized constant SessionsController::Xhome_path
- however, typing the mydomain.com/Xhome URL once this user is authenticated works well and brings the expected Xhome view, which seems to prove that there is no problem on the routes side.

Do you know where this NameError issue can come from ? Why can't I use Xhome_path just as I did with home_path ?

Comment: did you try `x_home` or `xhome` ? (all lowercase)

Comment: What does running "rake routes" say for the XHome section?

Comment: See Ruby constants on why `Xhome` might not be working.

Comment: @house9 : using lowercase (i.e. replacing Xhome by xhome everywhere) does work. Thank you very much...

Comment: @DamienRoche : Can you be more specific ? I googled Ruby Constants and found that they should start with an uppercase letter or should be camelcased. Does this imply that Xhome, because it starts with an uppercase letter, is considered a constant which therefore prevents Ruby to see Xhome_path as a path ?

Comment: @RyanWilcox : rake routes gives the following :                          home  /home(.:format) users#home and Xhome /Xhome(.:format) users#Xhome so the appropriate routes seem to exist (which is confirmed by the fact that typing the direct mydomain.com/Xhome URL works well). I do believe the issue was coming from the uppercase first letter.

Comment: @Pierre that's correct. The routes `home_path` etc are actually methods, whereas `Xhome_path` would be a constant. Rails constructs these helper methods dynamically, which would fail it were passed a constant-like name.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `rake routes` and check for the available route names and their corresponding path helpers. Check if the path name is actually `Xhome_path`. If no path name exist, then do

```
redirect_to '/Xhome', :notice => "Logged in successfully"
```

Comment: As per my above comment, rake routes gives the following :                          home  /home(.:format) users#home and Xhome /Xhome(.:format) users#Xhome so the appropriate routes seem to exist. Thanks and +1 for your functional solution that works around the use of _path and allows me to use capital letters if needed.

Comment: Try changing the capital X to small x, I guess that might be the problem.